# A Question on 'Topical Progression': How to Address Internal Inconsistencies in the Framework

Tags: written-language, writing, systemic-functional

(This question has been moved from English Language Stack Exchange on account of relevancy.)

In my mission to improve my writing, I have come across a concept called 'topical progression' (discussed [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi2pKmOgouEAxUKSkEAHQY6AogQFnoECBgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjournals.iupui.edu%2Findex.php%2Fteachingwriting%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F26241%2F24264%2F49528&usg=AOvVaw0ghOt9OygNLHc_olXnFuJF&opi=89978449)). This concept frequently comes up in articles discussing cohesion and coherence in text (predominantly academic, as opening any fiction novel throws this concept out the window), and while I understand the basic idea and agree that it has value, the way that it's presented seems inconsistent, if not entirely false.

It's too prescriptive.

The basic forms of topical progression are Parallel Progression, Sequential Progression, Extended Parallel Progression, and Extended Sequential Progression. Parallel Progression is where the topic (usually the subject) is repeated in the following independent clause, whereas Sequential Progression is where something mentioned in the comment (usually the predicate) becomes the subject of the following independent clause. The extended versions simply have another independent clause with a different subject before the sequence begins or resumes.

An example of Parallel Progression is this:

> I left the bedroom. I needed to find something in the kitchen.

If we inserted another sentence with a different subject in the middle (for example, 'The door opened with a creak'), this would become Extended Parallel Progression.

An example of Sequential Progression is this:

> I left the bedroom. The room was too cold.

As before, if we inserted another sentence with a different subject in the middle (for example, 'I needed to put the heating on'), this would become Extended Sequential Progression.

Now, according to a lot of these 'topical progression' articles, we should be following these structures religiously to ensure logical progression. That's all well and good in theory, but even in these very same articles, this principle isn't consistently adhered to.

On pages 74 to 75 of the paper linked above, there's a table that outlines the subjects of a piece of text about someone called Vanessa. The author of the paper says that the example paragraph is a good example of topical progression because it maintains focus, yet we can clearly see that sentence number 4 contains an independent clause beginning with the word 'money' (a word that has no semantic link to 'Vanessa,' unlike other subjects in the paragraph, such as 'her parents and her grandparents'). This very obvious anomaly is never addressed. The same is true for every article I've read on topical progression. They either provide perfect examples that follow their structures or conveniently ignore the anomalies.

The given-before-new principle, also mentioned in the article, would allow the insertion of a select number of random topics, such as 'money,' because there are plenty of concepts that the reader would be familiar with. However, across all of the articles, I've never seen anyone state that given-before-new supersedes topical progression; it merely acts as one justification as to why this structure is logical from a reader's perspective.

To get to the point, how do you think this inconsistency can be explained? Can it even be explained? I feel there must be a reason why outliers like 'money' aren't being mentioned, perhaps because it's a known concept (following given-before-new) and topical progression is less prescriptive than it is made to seem, allowing for certain non-linked diversions.

I wonder if 'money' in this sense follows parallel progression because it's synonymous with 'their money' instead of 'money' as a concept. Similarly, where the connection between the subject of a new clause and the previous one isn't so clear, I wonder if the subject can semantically relate to the whole clause, like a demonstrative (this or that) but less overt. For example, 'He was sweating. The sun was beating down.' Here 'the sun,' though not mentioned previously, follows the parallel structure by referring to 'Him sweating' and the inferred heat.

I am eager to find an answer because I want to make sure my understanding is sound for my own benefit and the benefit of someone whom I'm helping improve their writing at work.

Comment: I'm sorry but I just do not understand this at all. I do not think any of this will help you to  "improve your writing", it just provides labels for ways in which certain sentences work with each other. But when I google it, I get this as the first hit for academic writing: http://sana.aalto.fi/awe/cohesion/infostrux/flow/04topprog.html However, when you say improve my writing, what kind of writing do you mean? Essay writing, academic writing, news writing, etc. etc.

Comment: [cont'd] Your money example is really about **collocation**. On the face of it, money might collocate very well with Vanessa, her parents and grandparents. It is not necessarily an anomaly at all... As for "at work", there is also report writing, memo writing, etc.  Vanessa and money can collocate in that example, but in a mathematics article the word fecal is highly unlikely and probably does not collocate with the text. But, here is another level of collocation: https://www.englishpath.com/collocations-what-are-they-and-how-to-use-them/ So, to do work, not make it, generally and for example.

Comment: @Lambie I came across this framework by chance, probably reading about something entirely different (given before new, perhaps), and I found it interesting. In terms of how I intend to use it, I work for a company that requires lots of copy about products/categories (informational and sales), as well as blog articles. I'm teaching someone junior how to write copy, and they've struggled with creating coherent text, largely on account of stringing sentences together that don't connect. Outside of work, I write fiction, so that's another area where it could be relevant.

Comment: @Lambie, referring to your second comment, that makes a lot of sense. I've been reading into the research on thematic progression, and I think some academics would call 'money' a derived theme. Anne McCabe specifically mentions how lots of these themes form patterns of progression under the assumption that the reader has the worldly knowledge that the author assumes them to have. If, for whatever reason, we say that 'money' isn't derived, McCabe also talks about 'peripheral themes', which don't link to previous items in the text and yet remain important to the development of the message.

Comment: @Lambie A final note: the link you provided is where I first discovered the concept of topical progression. This resource, however, is very simplistic compared to some of the papers I have read since, which is likely why I'm finding lots of real-world examples that contradict the writing suggestions provided.

Comment: I tried to explain that what you are stating is an anomaly, is not one. I tried to explain about collocation in writing in that regard and provided a link. Finally, I don't think linguistics or the idea of topical progression is a good place to start (that junior is just starting, right)? Using this complicated topic will surely just confuse them.  There are all kinds of sites on the Internet that explain how to learn to write or write better, and the main idea about that is usually simpler is better. There is not enough space here for more pointers but lots of sites out htere are great.

Comment: Even without reading the Vanessa text. money collocates with family, parents and grandparents (concepts). Depending on what level of analysis you use (thematic or collocational), money collocates with family issues. And it neither peripheral to it nor derived from it. It can be fully at the center of those concepts. But again, none of this is useful to the task of helping a junior colleague improve their writing. Get samples of the type of writing you need and give those to the person to **read**. That will help.

Comment: Apologies if it hasn't come across. I agree with you that it isn't an anomaly. Your point was well made. I was just pointing to peripherals as a concept to explain cases where the links can't be made. And yes, the topic is too confusing for a junior - I'm using the framework to inform my teaching method (in terms of how I dissect the problems in their writing), but I'm not trying to get them to understand it. I give them very, very basic resources when I want them to read helpful articles.

Comment: Ok, Ada, I wish you the best in your endeavors.

Comment: Thank you. Always appreciate your comments, Lambie :)